# How tight should vinyl siding be against each other?

Tags: siding, vinyl, vinyl-siding

We are having vinyl siding installed, replacing very dented and mangled aluminum siding.

We are concerned, after the builders have finished one section of the driveway, about the shadows of the siding laps. I understand that vinyl siding should be able to move from side to side in order to permit expansion/contraction, but should we be able to stick fingers in between the laps and pull apart the seams from each other (this is double dutch lap siding)?

There are a few laps that we feel are correctly tight together, and others that extend further out and cast small shadows. Should we be concerned about these seams?

Comment: Pictures showing what you think may be incorrect will get better answers.

Comment: Are you saying that there *is* that much space, or that you're *able to create* that much space?

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like an excessive amount of space. Contact the manufacturer and get the installation instructions if they are doing it wrong it will void the warranty.

Comment: +1 For recommending to follow the manufacturer’s recommendation or you’ll void the warranty. It depends on 1) where you live, 2) temperature when it’s installed.